# Cannot connect to MySQL server on [remote host] (where remote host is through ngrok)

Tags: mysql, tcp, mysql-workbench, ngrok

I am currently trying to work through a guide to build an automated phone system using twilio and integrate it into MySQL database (https://www.twilio.com/blog/connect-local-database-twilio-functions). The issue I am having is that I am unable to connect to the MySQL server after tunneling with ngrok.

Here is the command I am running:

`mysql --protocol=tcp --host=0.tcp.ngrok.io --port 18477 --user=root -p`

When I press run, the terminal sits in idle for several minutes and then outputs:
`ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '0.tcp.ngrok.io' (110)`

Here is a screenshot of ngrok:

[image]

I have followed the steps in https://linuxize.com/post/mysql-remote-access/ to further my knowledge on setting up remote access to mysql. At the bottom of the article, it says that this error typically means 'the port 3306 is not open, or the MySQL server is not listening on the IP address." I then followed the links provided and checked both of those. The second image looked at the listening aspect.

Upon encountering this error, I tried to do some research to see if I can track down the issue. I have zero networking experience, so I do not understand anything beyond client and server basics and such. I came across the mysql documentation (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/can-not-connect-to-server.html).

It says, "if the server was started with skip_networking system variable, it will not accept TCP/IP connections at all." Furthermore, it goes on to say, "If the server was started with bind_address system variable set to 127.0.0.1, it will listen for TCP/IP connections only locally on loopback interface and will not accept remote connections."

I have already made the modifications that I have seen across various documentation and articles. Here are some images to show what I have set-up:

The image below is a screenshot from MySQL Workbench. My bind address is open to all and is not restricted to local connections (`bind_address` in `etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d` is commented out). Furthermore, port is set to 3306. Lastly, `skip-networking` is not checked so TCP/IP can occur.
[image]

To confirm that MySQL is listening on port 3306, I ran this `lsof` command with `iTCP:3306`. I believe this tells me that mysql is listening on 3306. I am not sure if `USER` refers to the user mysqld is running on, but if it is, I am not sure what this means in the context of `root` and other users.

[image]

I wish this seemed trivial, but with little networking knowledge, I can easily overlook something simple. Any additional information can be provided.

Comment: I have yet to figure this out.

Answer (score 0):

When you connect to MySql via the hostname set up by ngrok, don't use port 3306. Instead, use the port allocated for you by ngrok. In your example it's 18447.